# CLI to native byte array translation

Tags: c++, visual-c++, c++-cli

Here is my variant of translation byte array from CLI to native:

```
byte* GetNative(array<System::Byte, 1> ^ byteArray) {
    try {
        pin_ptr<unsigned char> array_pin = &byteArray[0];
        return (byte*) array_pin;
        }
    catch(...) {
        return 0;
        }
    }
```

My question is about `array_pin`. I think I need to delete it, but if I delete it then the variable with my `byte*` pointer will be broken (or at least could be broken.)

Is it safe to use this variant? Or, how and when must I delete `array_pin`? Is there easier way to implement bytes translation?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`array_pin` will become unpinned as soon as it goes out of scope, eg. when `GetNative` returns. The underlying managed array may then be moved or collected by the garbage collector, leaving the `byte*` you have returned dangling, which will result in breakage when it is dereferenced.

As `pin_ptr` can't be a member variable and you can't pass it back out of a function, you'll either need to do everything to the unmanaged array whilst `array_pin` is still in scope, or copy the data out of the pinned array and into somewhere else (like a `std::array`, for example).

Comment: keep the array pinned? make array_pin global?

Comment: Augh, no! You could wrap it in special class instance that provided an accessor that returned a `byte*`, or you could pass around the `pin_ptr` itself. Globals are almost never the answer.

Comment: Oops, don't think that keeping or passing around `pin_ptr` is actually allowed; it only has function scope lifetime. This is a good thing really, because you don't want to go locking up the managed heap by pinning bits of it all over the place. Answer updated to reflect that.

Comment: Yes, wrap in a CLI class and expose the pinned byte, so when the managed class goes out of scope and is collected, the pin_ptr becomes unpinned